# Trying to count number professors in dept order by desc

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT P.pID FROM Department D, Professor P
WHERE D.dID = P.dID
ORDER count(pID);
```

Mysql, keeps throwing an error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'count(pID)
LIMIT 0, 30' at line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a BY.

The query should be:

```
SELECT P.pID FROM Department D, Professor P
WHERE D.dID = P.dID
ORDER BY count(pID);
```

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER` needs to be `ORDER BY`.